# Redirecionar pagina passando header Authorization

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

Tenho uma aplicação de login onde o usuário digita o nome de usuário e senha,daí faço uma requisição POST com o ajax conforme o código abaixo:

```
<script >
    $(document).on('click',".entrar",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let name = document.getElementById('user').value;
        let pass = document.getElementById('pass').value;
        if(name.length && pass.length){
            $.ajax({
                url:"http://localhost:8081/auth/login",
                method:"POST",
                data:{
                    name:name,
                    pass:pass
                },
                async:true,
                success:function(data){
                    if(/Senha|Usuário/i.test(data)){
                        document.getElementById("alerta").style.display = "block";
                        $("#erro").html(data);
                    }else{

                    }
                },


            });
        }

    });


</script>
```

O retorno do ajax,na função de success, é uma mensagem informando se o usuário está incorreto ou a senha , isso se uma das informações estiverem incorretos,caso esteja tudo ok, o retorno é um token de autorização.
O que quero fazer, é caso estiver recebendo o token ,preciso redirecionar para http://localhost:8081/projects porém,preciso passar um header de autorização para esse link contendo o token seria algo como `'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token;`

Como faço pra assim que receber o token ,redirecionar a página passando esse token no header, a parte de redirecionamento estaria dentro do else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu suponho que você quer dizer redirecionamento por window.location = 'http://localhost:8081/projects', porem, até onde sei, é impossível redirecionar para uma página com cabeçalhos personalizados definidos, independentemente da linguagem ou da estrutura usada. Em outras palavras, não há como acionar um redirecionamento HTTP e fazer com que o cliente adicione um cabeçalho personalizado. Tanto que o redirecionamento por window.location seria usado na pagina de projects, no seu caso, quando o Header de Authorization fosse invalido, iria redirecionar para a pagina de login novamente sem nenhum header personalizado.

A única maneira de um site instruir um navegador a emitir uma solicitação HTTP com um cabeçalho personalizado é usar o ajax, para quando a pagina redirecionada, ao carregar, fazer uma chamada ajax, enviando o header Authorization que se obteve na pagina de login e que foi salva no navegador, e no server-side, validar esse header e enviar os dados que serão exibidos na página, caso invalido, pelo proprio javascript client-side usar o window.location para redirecionar novamente para a página de login. E ele precisa do CORS implementado no servidor de destino para permitir tais solicitações ajax.

Comment: Seria algo como ao abrir a pagina ele mandar a requisição get com o header ,isso?

Answer (score 2):

O servidor irá enviar o header Authorization em sua resposta, ou seja, após executar a requisição, você pode obter o header da seguinte forma dentro da função "success:

```
success: function(data, textStatus, request){
         const token = request.getResponseHeader('Authorization');
         if(token){ 
            localStorage.setItem('token', token);
            window.location = 'http://localhost:8081/projects';
         }
},
```

Ao invés de enviar o token no cabeçalho, você pode guardar numa localStorage, e verificar após o redirecionamento se ela existe e é válida.

Comment: Entendi,obrigado